# Author page not found

Tags: 404-error

Author page is not found on url mytabletguru(.)com/author/TabletGuru/

By Author Tablet Guru there is around 250+ post. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question. Are you using custom post types?

Comment: Nope.. What more details I needed to add?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a temporary issue specificially with your theme. This might be caused by any plugin you are using. I will suggest you to deactivate all plugins for a moment and see if the problem is solved. If yes, you can activate one plugin at a time to find which plugin is creating issue then either remove it or replace it with better alternative. In my guess, you might have disabled author page using plugin or theme setting.